# how can I pass parameters to joomla component correctly?

Tags: php, joomla, get, components, joomla-extensions

I want to send a parameter to a joomla component by Get method

This is The URL:

```
index.php?option=com_bahaedini&search=keyword&view=items&year=yyyy&month=mm&&day=dd
```

ex:

```
index.php?option=com_bahaedini&search=ebooks&view=items&year=2000&month=1&&day=20
```

This is ParseRoute function:

```
function BahaediniParseRoute($segments)
{
       $vars = array();


       switch($segments[0])
       {

               case 'items':
                       $vars['view'] = 'items';

                       if(isset($segments[2]))
                       {
                       $year = explode( ':', $segments[2] );
                       $vars['year'] =  (int)$year[0];
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[3]))
                       {
                       $month = explode( ':', $segments[3] );
                       $vars['month'] = (int)$month[0]; 
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[4]))
                       {
                       $day = explode( ':', $segments[4] );
                       $vars['day'] = (int)$day[0]; 
                       }

                       if(isset($segments[1]))
                       {
                       $search = explode( ':', $segments[1] );
                       $vars['search'] = (int)$search[0]; 
                       }

                       break; 


       }
       return $vars;
```

Normally The URL changes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/component/bahaedini/items/ebooks/1395/1/8
```

I print them with this method:

```
echo "<br>s:".$_ss          = urldecode($app->input->getString('search'));
echo "<br>y:".$_yy          = urldecode($app->input->getString('year'));
echo "<br>m:".$_mm          = urldecode($app->input->getString('month'));
echo "<br>d:".$_dd          = urldecode($app->input->getString('day'));
```

result:

```
ss=ebook/yy=2000/mm=1/dd=8
```

every thing is normal UNTIL:
If I remove keyword this is the result:

```
ss=2000/yy=1/mm=8/dd=
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JInput which is the API for managing requests.  It's very simple to get anything from the url with JInput. http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$year = $jinput->getInteger('year'); // not sure why you have year as a string
$keyword = $jinput->getString('keyword');
```

If you are using Joomla the whole point is to use the API so that you don't have to write things from scratch.